# English words by CEFR level - open source

Tags: electronic-resources, vocabulary, english, cefr

Are there any open source data that categorizes English words based on CEFR levl and is available to download?
As an example I found https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlists/oxford3000-5000 , which categorizes English words based on CEFR level, but it has license.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following free open source resources:

- https://www.coe.int/en/web/common-european-framework-reference-languages/reference-level-descriptions
- For levels from A1 to B2 there are some textbooks for English vocabulary on the Books4Languages website that you can access and receive a Creative Commons license (for example, here is the link for the A1 level https://open.books4languages.com/english-a1-vocabulary/ ).
- For levels C1 and C2 there are two papers provided by the University of Macedonia and that you can access and download for free from here: https://www.toe.gr/pluginfile.php?file=%2F2143%2Fmod_resource%2Fcontent%2F1%2FLevel%20C1%20Word%20List.pdf for C1 and https://www.toe.gr/pluginfile.php?file=%2F2144%2Fmod_resource%2Fcontent%2F1%2FLevel%20C2%20Word%20List.pdf for C2.

Answer (score -1):

[This link](https://www.toe.gr/course/view.php?id=27) appears to have a few lists of words based on level. It's not sortable like the EVR, but the content is still there.

I'd recommend putting the words into something like [Anki](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/english). Anki has open source flashcard sets, so anyone can use the flashcards that other people upload to it, and they allow you to flip through flashcards giving each a rate of confidence that will determine how often the word shows up again. It looks like they don't have a dataset for English CEFR vocabulary by level, but I have seen some lower level CEFR vocab sets on [quizlet](https://quizlet.com/415688232/cefr-flash-cards/)

It also looks like although the vocabulary lists are licensed, you can use a [text analysis tool](http://englishprofile.org/index.php/wordlists/text-inspector) from the same website for free to test your writing skills after you've gotten more of the vocabulary down.

Comment: This data is not open source